# contract violation expected: number? given: #<procedure:runtime> argument position: 2nd other arguments...: 1535481725945

Tags: scheme, sicp

Try to check imput number to even in this code:

```
(define (square n)
  (* n n))
(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (find-divisor n 2))

(define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
  (cond
    ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)
    ((divides? test-divisor n) test-divisor)
    (else (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))

(define (divides? a b)
  (= (remainder b a) 0))

(define (prime? n)
  (= n (smallest-divisor n)))

(define (runtime)
  (current-milliseconds))

(define (timed-prime-test n)
  (newline)
  (display n)
  (start-prime-test n runtime 1))

(define (start-prime-test n start-time count)
  (if (prime? n)
    (report-prime (- (runtime) start-time)
                  (+ count 1)
                  (display "tut"))
    (+ n 1))
  (if (even? n)
    (+ n 1)
    (display "n is uneven"))
  (if (= count 3)
    (display "done")
    (start-prime-test (+ n 1) runtime count)))

(define (report-prime elapsed-time)
  (display " *** ")
  (display elapsed-time))

(timed-prime-test 4)
```

And see this error:

> ```
> contract violation 
>   expected: number?
>   given: #<procedure:runtime>
>   argument position: 2nd 
>   other arguments...: 1535481725945
> ```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You are using `+` very strangely in the if statements of `start-prime-test`. You are using it to calculate a number, but then throwing that number away. It looks as if you intended for those `+` expressions to be a side-effect or an imperative action, but you don't use those either except for `display`.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is with two uses of the `runtime` function. The error message says that it got the *function* `runtime` where it expected a number; probably the result of *calling* the function. That means somewhere you're referring to the function without calling it.

This:

```
> runtime
#<procedure:runtime>
```

Instead of this:

```
> (runtime)
1535490725945
```

Keep in mind that to call a function you have to wrap it in parentheses, even if it's a zero-argument function.

You use the `runtime` function in 3 places, and in 2 of those (within `timed-prime-test` and within the 3rd if statement of `start-prime-test`), you're using the bare function without calling it.

Changing those 2 places from `runtime` to `(runtime)` gets rid of the `contract violation  expected: number?  given: #<procedure:runtime>` error.

This solves your first problem.

However there is another error behind it:

> ```
> report-prime: arity mismatch;
>  the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
>   expected: 1
>   given: 3
>   arguments...:
>    0
>    2
>    #<void>
> ```

This comes from your call to `report-prime` within the first if statement of the `start-prime-test` function.

I don't know what you intended for this code or for the `report-prime` function to do. It might be that the definition is wrong and it should take more parameters, or it might be that the call is wrong and should pass in only one argument.

Which one did you intend?

#### Update: Calling `report-prime` with 1 argument and then performing 2 actions

> I want to pass only 1 param into it (`(- (runtime) start-time)`) and after it performs the function I want to consistently perform two actions (`(+ count 1)` and `(display "tut")`)

To perform a bunch of actions, you should use `begin` like this:

```
(begin
  action1
  action2
  ...)
```

Now, the `(+ count 1)` is not an "action", but that's a separate problem. If you intended for it to be an action, then it would go within this `begin` block.

That means, within the first if statement of `start-prime-test`, replacing this:

```
(report-prime (- (runtime) start-time)
              (+ count 1)
              (display "tut"))
```

With this:

```
(begin
  (report-prime (- (runtime) start-time))
  (+ count 1)
  (display "tut"))
```

With that change, the `report-prime: arity mismatch` error goes away.

This solves your second problem.

There is another problem behind that, an infinite loop. Your code prints:

> ```
> 4 *** 0tutn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is 
> unevenn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is uneven
> *** 0tutn is unevenn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is 
> uneven *** 0tutn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is unevenn is uneven *** 0tutn is unevenn is uneven
> ```

And it keeps going like that, never stopping.

I suggest you ask a separate question to solve that, since an infinite loop is a different type of problem to solve than a contract violation.

However, first you might want to read a tutorial on how to use recursion in functional programming. The gist of it is that there needs to be a base case, where it always stops, and any recursive cases you need to get "closer" to the base case, for some definition of closer.

Comment: I want report-prime function to display "***" and to show how much time need to check n for simplicity. And it call if expression is true.I suppose that compiller think that i pass 3 param in this functian. But i want to pass only 1 param in it((- (runtime) start-time)) and after perfom the function i want consistently perform two actions((+ count 1) and(display "tut")). But it is something wrong in if syntax i think.

Comment: The problem with that is that `(+ count 1)` is not an action. `(+ count 1)` is just like `count + 1` in imperative languages; it produces a number, but it doesn't mutate `count` as a variable.

Comment: By the way, if you want to perform a bunch of actions, you should use `begin` like this: `(begin action1 action2 ...)`